# Prevent unnecessary increase of line spacing after in-line equation

Tags: line-spacing, inline

In the following example, line spacing is increased even though there is no text below the equation requiring the extra space:
[image]
Is there a way to prevent this? Using `\\[-5pt]` at the end of the line prevents the increase but it also shortens the line slightly:[image]

Comment: you are disabling the features of inline math by using `\limits`  the reason the subscript moves to the subscript position is exactly the issue you raise, but by forcing `\limits` you break that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two possibilities. In the picture, I show the three results: the first is what you get, the second is the preferred way, the third can be used, but this adjustment has to be made ***only*** when the document is in its final form so changes in wording will not risk to make the lines to clash.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Spaced out}

If $F$ is a closed subset of $R^k$, put $\rho_F(x)=\inf\limits_{t\in F}\lvert x-t\rvert$.
Then $\rho_F$ is continuous on $R^k$, and $\rho_F(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in F$.

\subsubsection*{Normal way}

If $F$ is a closed subset of $R^k$, put $\rho_F(x)=\inf_{t\in F}\lvert x-t\rvert$.
Then $\rho_F$ is continuous on $R^k$, and $\rho_F(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in F$.

\subsubsection*{No spacing}

If $F$ is a closed subset of $R^k$, put $\smash[b]{\rho_F(x)=\inf\limits_{t\in F}\lvert x-t\rvert}$.
Then $\rho_F$ is continuous on $R^k$, and $\rho_F(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in F$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Generally, you should avoid the unadorned `\smash`, preferring to just smash what's really wanted. Why is it risky? Suppose you change your mind and add a couple of words to the second line. Here's what can happen with `\smash[b]`:

[image]

And here's the same without `\limits`.

[image]

Can you see why the “normal way” is preferred?

Comment: I would not call this "normal way".

Comment: What is a good use of smash ?

Comment: @projetmbc This *might* be a good use, for the final revision of the document. It's also handy in displays, where there's much more control even during the initial phases.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.